# Xamarin Forms Image. Проблема загрузки изображения по URL

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Есть задача загрузить на ContentPage в listbox изображения по ссылкам из интернета.
Берем список картинок и грузим. Некая малая часть картинок не отображается. Хотя из браузера они прекрасно доступны.
Читаем Интернет и находим информацию что нужно в опциях Android установить

HttpClientImplementation = Managed
а SSL/TLS в Native TLS 1.2+

Это не помогло. Поиск по инету тоже показывает что далеко не всем помогает.
Еще как вариант предлагается использовать ffimageloading
Однако, эта библиотека ведет себя также.

Проблема связана с SSL.

Для проверки(теста) берем пустой проект. Кладем на него image и пытаемся показать картинку.
код:

```
       public string img1 = "https://zhenskoe-mnenie.ru/upload/information_system_14/1/3/2/item_13266/information_items_13266.jpg";
        public string img2 = "https://ic.pics.livejournal.com/koparev/70195450/27486/27486_600.jpg";
        public string img3 = "https://101kote.ru/upload/resize_cache/iblock/459/770_500_240cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a/manul.jpg";
        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            imgTest.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData(img3)));

        }
```

Картинка img1 отображается

Картинка img2 отображается

Картинка img3 НЕотображается

Потому 2 вопроса.
Кто-то знает всё-таки как загрузить такую картинку?
Или как заранее определить что картинка не будет загружена?

Спасибо.

Comment: А вы смотрели через браузер, в чем там разница в этих ссылках в плане TLS?  Еще `WebClient` признан устаревшим, рекомендуется использовать `HttpClient` вместо него. Это тоже потенциально может помочь.

Comment: В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) написано, что транспорт для `HttpClient` может быть настроен при сборке, это на случай, если проблема именно в поведении `HttpWebRequest`, который является транспортом для `WebClient`.

Comment: @aepot не представляю что я должен сделать.  любые попытки работать с HttpClient приводят к System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
  Message=The SSL connection could not be established,

Comment: кажется что-то получилось. Добавив эту троку начала картинка грузится ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; }; Пока проверю в основной программе. Так всегда. Пол дня ничего не получается. А как напишешь вопрос начинает получаться.

Comment: добавляя эту строчку вы делаете огромную дыру в безопасности, сводя весь смысл TLS на нет.

Comment: @aepot Буду благодарен за правильное решение. Меня устроит решение которое подскажет заранее что такая картинка не будет загружена. И я удалю ее из коллекции.

Comment: Еще вам надо познакомиться [вот с этим](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects), например сейчас вы игнорируете тот факт, что `WebClient` - `IDisposable` (`HttpClient` кстати тоже), это нехорошо, особенно если вы хотите писать полноценные приложения, а не просто играться с эмулятором.

Comment: Я не подскажу вам правильное решение, потому что не пишу под телефоны, и не знаком с тонкостями мобильных сетевых возможностей. Но может кто-то кроме меня подскажет. Так что извиняйте. Кстати, если это андройд, добавьте в вопрос соответствующую метку.

Comment: Кстати, только сейчас обратил внимание, вы пишете что `HttpClientImplementation` не помогло. Так оно поможет только как раз при использовании `HttpClient`, потому что `WebClient` - это только `HttpWebRequest`, и оно не настраивается.

Answer (score 0):

Решение.
добавить
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
полный текст

```
        public string img1 = "https://zhenskoe-mnenie.ru/upload/information_system_14/1/3/2/item_13266/information_items_13266.jpg";
        public string img2 = "https://ic.pics.livejournal.com/koparev/70195450/27486/27486_600.jpg";
        public string img3 = "https://101kote.ru/upload/resize_cache/iblock/459/770_500_240cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a/manul.jpg";

        public MainPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            imgTest.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData(img3)));

        }
```